# How can I set the time zone in Eclipse (wrong cvs log time stamps)?

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, timezone, cvs

When I check in a file in CVS using Eclipse, a log entry is automatically added to the checked-in file, e.g.

```
/*
 * $$Log: $$
 */
```

becomes

```
/*
 * $Log: IniTechPlan.java,v $
 * Revision 1.1  2011/09/06 15:00:00  michael.bolton
 * Added.
 *
 */
```

The problem is that the when the local time is 17:00 (my time zone is GMT+2) the log entry time written by Eclipse is 15:00. The time on the cvs server is correct, and using other CVS clients the time stamp is also correct. So it seems like the problem is that the Eclipse ignores the time zone information and writes the GMT time to the log entry.

Based on some googling it seems like I'm not alone with this problem (see e.g. http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/153139/482527/), but I haven't found any solution. Is there some way to corrify this issue (sensibly, without changing the CVS server time)?

**Update:**

Apparently, as pointed out by KARASZI István, the problem is not within Eclipse but on the CVS server, which writes the log information. When or if I find a solution I'll update this question.

Answer (score 4):

The [RCS information](http://badgertronics.com/writings/cvs/keywords.html) is written by the CVS server, not the Eclipse IDE.

The time entries are written in GMT there. I don't really know how to change this, but I'm sure that Eclipse is not affected.

As I'm reading CVS is using timezone of the server to print information, so you can try to change the `TZ` environment variable before starting the cvs server. That could help.

*Example:*

```
$ TZ='Indian/Comoro' date
Tue Sep  6 16:50:36 EAT 2011
```

and

```
$ TZ='Europe/Budapest' date
Tue Sep  6 15:51:06 CEST 2011
```

So it would be:

```
TZ='Europe/Budapest' cvspserver
```

*Update2*:

After checking out the CVS source code, it seems it is using the GMT timezone to put log informations.

There is no `localtime` support in it, except in the history command (`-z` option). So no luck for you, unless you modify the source of the CVS server.

Comment: You're right, Eclipse seems to just receive the file from the server, which substitutes the placeholder with the time data and more. Using the TZ environment variable didn't work, we'll continue to search for a solution on the server.